# How to trigger function by using check boxes in nstableview, in swift

Tags: swift, cocoa, checkbox, nstableview

I have nstableview in mac application. One column has names, second - numbers and third has checkboxes. When user make checkbox ON this should trigger function according to the name in first column in the same row. To have the name from first column (for triggering function) I need to know row index, and I use function rowForView(_ view: NSView). Question is what I should use as parameter (_ view: NSView) in this function. Below is the code. I am not sure if I am going in right direction to get what I have described above.

Related question is how I can get array of names from first column of table. I need this because if I will sort table according to the name then I cannot use my array, which used as data to fill the nstableview, I need array of sorted names to correctly trigger function.

```
  @IBOutlet weak var myCheckbox: NSButton!

  @IBAction func checkboxToShowRestrctaseSites(sender: AnyObject) {
     if myCheckbox.state == NSOnState
    {
        let objectOfPresentRestrictase = RestrictasesSorting(restrictase: "",  dna: inputDnaFromUser.string!)
        var tableOfNumberedRestrictase = objectOfPresentRestrictase.makeListOfPresentRestrictase()
        var listOfAllRestrictaseWithSites = objectOfPresentRestrictase.searchForRestrictionSiteInList().1

        var row = myTable.rowForView(_ view: NSView)
        var name = Array(tableOfNumberedRestrictase.keys)[row]
        var site = listOfAllRestrictaseWithSites[name]
```

**UPDATE**
I have found that triggering function start to work if I remove if myCheckbox.state == NSOnState, and when I used sender as NSView as parameter for function rowForView. To control the ON and Off state I can also use sender in if condition. Code below.

```
 @IBAction func checkboxToShowRestrctaseSites(sender: AnyObject){
 if sender.state == NSOnState
 {
        let objectOfPresentRestrictase = RestrictasesSorting(restrictase: "",  dna: inputDnaFromUser.string!)
        var tableOfNumberedRestrictase = objectOfPresentRestrictase.makeListOfPresentRestrictase()
        var listOfAllRestrictaseWithSites = objectOfPresentRestrictase.searchForRestrictionSiteInList().1

        var row = myTable.rowForView(sender as! NSView)
        var name = Array(tableOfNumberedRestrictase.keys)[row]
        var site = listOfAllRestrictaseWithSites[name]
```

Comment: Datasource or bindings?

Comment: @Willeke  -  Datasource

Comment: sender is the checkbox which was switched on or off. Instead of myCheckbox you should use sender.

Comment: @Willeke, Thanks, I have found this already. Now, problem is to put control on the ON and OFF state. I have found that I can use again sender for if statement. I need to find out also what to put in else condition for OFF state to switch back my text to state before the triggering function which was induced by switching checkbox to ON state.

Comment: I don't know what the text was and what your action does.

Comment: @Willeke, I have used attributedstring to mark some parts of text when checkbox is ON, and I would like to have the text without marked part, previous state of text, when checkbox is OFF.

Comment: You have to store both the attributed text and the plain text. Or get the plain text from the attributed text.

Comment: @Willeke, also, I have several checkboxes to mark different parts of text and ideally it would be to have situation, when adding checkbox on ON state will add the marked parts. When opposite action, when I switched checkbox OFF then according marked part is disappear. When all ON all according parts are marked, and for all OFF checkboxes states text is not marked.

Comment: You have to calculate the attributed string every time you switch a checkbox on or off.

Comment: This has nothing to do with actions and you should ask a new question.

Answer (score 2):

The documentation of rowForView:

> Return Value
>
> The index of the row corresponding to the view. Returns -1 if view is not an instance of NSTableRowView or a subview of an instance of NSTableRowView. In other words, if view is not in a table view, this method returns -1. (Note that this method may also return -1 when a row is being animated away, because view no longer has a valid row.).

Sounds like you can use the checkbox.

Your datasource does the sorting and has the data for the first column.